# Linkifying text to a specific paragraph in a same layout

Tags: android

Is it possible to link directly to a paragraph from a text link (perhaps using "linkify")?

For example, I have a table of contents with the following:

- Definition
- signs & symptoms
- treatment
- etc.

In the same layout I have the text or headings that which correspond to these entries. I want a click on the text in the table of contents to jump to that specific heading in my content: e.g. I click on "signs & symptoms" and this jumps directly to the section marked "signs and symptoms" in the content.

Thanks.

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Atherosclerosis"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent,ScrollViewCount" >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/tablecontentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FAFAD2" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/table" />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/definitionid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Definition" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/RiskFactors" />
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Pathophysiology" />
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/SignsandSymptoms" />
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Diagnosis" />
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Treatment" />
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Prevention" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_below="@+id/tablecontentlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/atherodefinition" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Definition"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/atherosclerosisdefinition"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
          <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/RiskFactors"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Modifiable"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/modifiableatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Nonmodifiable"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nonmodifiableatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
          <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Pathophysiology"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pathophysiologyatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/SignsandSymptoms"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
         <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/atherosclerosissignsandsymptoms"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Diagnosis"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
         <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Diagnosisatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Treatment"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
         <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/treatmentatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Prevention"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
         <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Preventionatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see some of your layout - are the different sections in different TextViews, or one big TextView? Is the parent container a ScrollView, or do all sections fit onto one screen with no issue?

Comment: could you please post your layout and source code , so that we can help you .

Comment: please find the above code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [linkify text to a paragraph heading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369586/linkify-text-to-a-paragraph-heading)