# linkify text to a paragraph heading

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Is it possible to link directly to a paragraph from a text link (perhaps using "linkify")?

For example, I have a table of contents with the following:

Definition
signs & symptoms
treatment
etc.
In the same layout I have the text or headings that which correspond to these entries. I want a click on the text in the table of contents to jump to that specific heading in my content: e.g. I click on "signs & symptoms" and this jumps directly to the section marked "signs and symptoms" in the content.

Thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Atherosclerosis"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent,ScrollViewCount" >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/tablecontentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FAFAD2" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/table" />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/definitionid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Definition" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/RiskFactors" />
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Pathophysiology" />
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/SignsandSymptoms" />
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Diagnosis" />
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Treatment" />
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4682B4"
        android:text="@string/Prevention" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_below="@+id/tablecontentlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/atherodefinition" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Definition"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/atherosclerosisdefinition"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
          <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/RiskFactors"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Modifiable"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/modifiableatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Nonmodifiable"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nonmodifiableatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
          <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Pathophysiology"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pathophysiologyatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/SignsandSymptoms"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
         <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/atherosclerosissignsandsymptoms"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Diagnosis"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
         <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Diagnosisatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Treatment"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
         <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/treatmentatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Prevention"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:textColor="#483D8B"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
         <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Preventionatherosclerosis"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

public class Atherosclerosis extends Activity {

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.atherosclerosis);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.definitionid);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {


           }

        });
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.atherosclerosis, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [scrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) method of ScrollView.

Set an OnClickListener on the headings, and in the onClick method, get the X coordinate of the top of the paragraph using the [getTop method from View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop%28%29) and scroll down to that position.

For example :

```
TextView signsAndSymptomsHeader;
ScrollView scrollView;

// do necessary initializations of Views, setup etc ...
// then the following in your onCreate method

signsAndSymptomsHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
             case R.id.id_of_signs_symptoms_content :
                 scrollView.scrollTo(0,v.getTop());
                 break;
             // repeat for all headers.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: here is my java activity

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like you tried my solution at all. Also, you didn't tell me what problems you had with what I suggested, so I can't really help you...